# noexcept operator fails after calling pointer-to-member function

Tags: c++, clang, noexcept

This MWE may appear contrived, but the failing static_assert is surprising nonetheless:

```
#include <utility>

struct C {
  void f() noexcept { }
  using F = void(C::*)();

  static constexpr F handler() noexcept {
    return &C::f;
  }

  void g() noexcept(noexcept((this->*handler())())) {
  }
};

int main() {
  static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<C>().g()));
}
```

Wandbox link: https://wandbox.org/permlink/a8HSyfuyX1buGrbZ

I would expect this to work on Clang but not GCC due to their different treatments of "this" in the context of operator noexcept.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If one of the answers answered your question, you can accept it. If both didn't answer your question, can you explain why so that we can improve our answers?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay; I wasn't satisfied with the answers but I'll accept one since they answer the question as it was phrased. However, in my case, "f" is a template parameter passed by a user of the library, so I need to query the noexcept-ness of of the function type to properly declare the noexcept specifier of the pointer to member function. Unfortunately, even when I add noexcept to the type alias, it doesn't compile because my alias for F is templated, which causes an internal compiler error. I will post a Clang bug about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as your `static_assert` has no string argument, you are using C++17. In C++17, `noexcept` became part of the type system. What this means is that given:

```
using F = void(C::*)();
```

This PMF is not `noexcept`. Calling it is equivalent to calling a `noexcept(false)` member function. You need to mark the function type as `noexcept`:

```
using F = void(C::*)() noexcept;
```

That change allows your code to compile:

```
#include <utility>

struct C {
  void f() noexcept { }
  using F = void(C::*)() noexcept;

  static constexpr F handler() noexcept {
    return &C::f;
  }

  void g() noexcept(noexcept((this->*handler())())) {
  }
};

int main() {
  static_assert(noexcept(std::declval<C>().g()));
}
```

<sup>[On Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/NUQtHb)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`f` is `noexcept`, but the pointer to it is not.  So in the definition of `g`, `this->*handler()` returns a PMF which is not `noexcept` (even though you happen to return the address of a MF that *is* `noexcept`, so when you call that by writing `(this->*handler())()` then you are calling a function which is not `noexcept`, so the `noexcept` clause there returns `false`.

Add `noexcept` to the end of line 5 and it works.